# Single command to rename a file to the first N characters of its hash

Tags: shell-script

I'm on macOS Mojave.

I hate having to name images when adding them to my website (Jekyll, for anyone who cares). Instead, I think a reasonable strategy is to generate a hash based on the contents of the file and use the first N characters of the hash as the file name. This strategy also helps with versioning my assets when serving the website out of Amazon S3 and CloudFront.

### Example

Given a file `somescreenshot.png`, I would run this TBD command and the result is the renamed file `8dbm2hz1.png`.

### Progress

I've made progress on this front but currently it's a multi-step approach.

1. Generate the hash, take the first eight characters and send to the clipboard.
   `shasum -a 256 -b inputfile.png | head -c8 | pbcopy`
2. Rename the file.
   `mv inputfile.png [paste from #1]`

I need to make this command an efficient piped, single step process.

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!"  Accepting an answer also indicates to _future_ readers that the answer actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use:

```
mv -- inputfile.png "$(shasum -a 256 -b inputfile.png | head -c8)"
```

It will move your file to the output of `$(shasum -a 256 -b inputfile.png | head -c8)` i.e. first 8 character of the hash.

Answer (score 3):

Use command substitution to save the hash in a shell variable:

```
file=inputfile.png
h=$(shasum -a 256 -b "$file" | head -c8)
```

Then you can use it for renaming, printing to the terminal, sending to `pbcopy`, or whatever.

```
mv -- "$file" "$h"
echo "$h" | pbcopy
echo "'$file' renamed to '$h'"
```

If you want to keep the file extension, use something like this:

```
newname=$h.${file##*.}
mv -- "$file" "$newname"
```

(`${var##*.}` removes everything up to the last dot.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename *all* files, then use xargs. This is an incantation of GNU tools, check your man pages to see if the corresponding options exist.

```
printf "%s\0" * |
    xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'echo mv "$1" "$(shasum -a 256 -b "$1"| head -c8)"' sh {}
```

This uses the null byte to separate filenames, which makes working with filenames that contain whitespace a safe operation.

The `echo` command is to be removed to actually move the files.